# maintenance theme on every page

Tags: 7, theming

On every page, maintenance theme is getting applied along with the user login boxes below the page after logging in. This is the state of the site which was handed over to me. I think this exists from a long time and no one gave importance to this issue.

This is my body tag obtained from inspect element (Chrome)

```
body class="marinelli html front logged-in no-sidebars page-newmain toolbar toolbar-drawer admin-menu" id="maintenance-page" style="padding-top: 65px;">
```

Please help me with this issue.

**edit:
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at marinelli:133**
This is the information obtained from inspecting element. 
It seems to be present in CDATA.. Where can i find CDATA?

```
    //grab all header rows
    $('th').each(function (column) {
        $(this).addClass('sortable').click(function () {
                var findSortKey = function ($cell) {
                    return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase()+ ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Go to `admin/config/development/maintenance` and uncheck the  `Put site into maintenance mode`.

Comment: What is a maintenance theme? Drupal 7 can have a default theme and an admin theme. As far as I know there is no such thing as a maintenance theme. You have configured an admin theme as the site default? In that case you should be able to go to the appearance settings and choose another theme.

Answer (score 0):

***Debugging is the art of removing all possible reasons why some unexpected/undesired issue arises ...*** so make sure your site is NOT in maintenance mode ...

To do so, navigate to `admin/config/development/maintenance` and ensure that "*Put site into maintenance mode*" is NOT (repeat: NOT) checked.

Comment: its not in maintenance mode.. I can  see sites content on that page layout and site functionality. Everythings working.. its just that site's theme is loading from maintenance page.